# Get subject key identifier from certificate

Tags: python, cryptography, certificate, pyopenssl

Is it possible to extract the [subject key identificator][1] from an existing certificate with python?

I tried someting like:

```
from OpenSSL.crypto import load_certificate, FILETYPE_PEM
        
cert_string='-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE--...'
certificate=load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, plain_cert)
subject=certificate.get_subject()
```

But it gives back the subject of the certificate. It seems like the certificate object doesn't offer functions for the subject key identifier. Are there other options?
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.2

Answer (score 5):

The code that will extract subject key identifier:

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_data, default_backend())
ski = cert.extensions.get_extension_for_oid(x509.oid.ExtensionOID.SUBJECT_KEY_IDENTIFIER)
print(ski.value.digest)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
subject=certificate.get_extension(0)
```

did the job. With

```
certificate.get_extension_count()
```

you can check how much extensions the certificate has.